# Robot Framework/Jenkins: chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH error

Tags: jenkins, path, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am able to open browser with  the following Robot Framework test:

```
Onboard The Customers     
    Open Browser  https://xxxxxxxxxx/xx     chrome
```

The Chromedriver is in my home diretory and the PATH is correctly set.

However, now I want to run the project in jenkins. So, I copied the chromedriver to JENKINS_HOME (/var/lib/jenkins). Set the PATH to include this directory.

Changed RF test to:

```
Onboard The Customers   
    Set Environment Variable  webdriver.chrome.driver  /var/lib/jenkins/chromedriver  
    Open Browser  https://xxxxxxxxxx/xx     chrome
```

I am not able to et over this error mesg:

```
Onboard The Customers                                                
 [ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open
Test Start Time: 20170504 12:22:42.512
Test End Time: 20170504 12:22:42.541
| FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: What version of Chrome Driver are you using? Try using the latest one.

Comment: I am using the latest: 2.29

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the PATH that I set up in the jenkins job. So, once I corrected that the test is now running.